# Prevent recalculations of User Defined Functions used in named ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have three UDF's:

```
Private Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

This function checks if something is in the array.

```
Private Function data_to_array(data As Range)

Dim arrArray As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim z As Integer

z = 0

ReDim arrArray(1 To data.Cells.Count)
For Each cell In data
    z = z + 1
    arrArray(z) = cell.Value
Next cell

data_to_array = arrArray
End Function
```

This function extracts selected range values and puts them into an array.

```
Private Function plot_vals(data As Variant, custom_arr As Variant)

Dim arrPlot As Variant
ReDim arrPlot(1 To UBound(data)) As Variant
Dim c As Integer
Dim cl As Integer

cl = 0

For c = 1 To UBound(data)
    cl = cl + 1
    If IsInArray(cl, custom_arr) Then
        arrPlot(cl) = data(cl)
    Else
        arrPlot(cl) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
Next c

plot_vals = arrPlot
End Function
```

The last UDF loops through the data array from second UDF and if index/position of value in data_array is in custom_array, then it returns its value. Otherwise it puts an error into an array.

Data looks like this:
[image]

These functions are used like this in Excel:

`data_to_array(A1:A5)` - this UDF creates an array(1 to 5) with values from cells A1:A5.

`plot_vals(data_to_array(A1:A5), {1,5})` - this UDF creates an array(1 to 5), and uses second argument to retrieve first and fifth values while putting errors in the other indexes. The result is array of for example: `{5,error,error,error,1}`

If I used the function on above data like this: `plot_vals(data_to_array(A1:A5), {1,2})` then the result would be an array `{5,4,error,error,error}`

That plot_vals UDF is used in named range and that named range is used to plot values on chart.
Data is stored in named range myData and the function in second named range is used like this:
`plot_vals(myData,{1,5})`.

Everything works, I can plot it on chart, all is good but **when the named ranges are used on charts, every time I change something in my workbook all functions are recalculated like... 10 times each one**, instead of **once**. It causes Excel to slow down/freeze if those functions are used many times. I have tried to search about function volatility and how to turn it off (it should be turned off by default?), but nothing seems to be working and I do not know how to stop that from happening. I have tried to recreate this in Excel using standard Excel functions in named ranges, but I cannot find a correct function to do what I want. UDF is exactly what I need.

When these named ranges are NOT used in charts then nothing happens, but **as soon as I use the named range on chart then it recalculates everything on even a minor change of a workbook**. Minor change meaning - copying / pasting / adding rows etc.

How can I stop that from happening? How to recalculate UDF's only once?

### ***EDIT on further research***:

I have tried the potential solutions provided by Charles Williams:
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-7-udfs-calculated-multiple-times/

His potential solutions do not change anything.

I have also tried using Sheet_Change event, changing calculations to manual and then back to automatic. It helps but it clears the clipboard (unacceptable) and it causes issues with my other macros, so it is a "no-go" solution.

It is also worth noting, that as soon as the chart is deleted and the UDF's remain in named ranges, everything is working nice and smooth. But when those named ranges are in chart series formulas, everything is recalculating 100's of times.

Comment: Typically how large are the input ranges you're using, and how many instances of the UDF's (and how many charts) ?

Comment: Input ranges consist of 5-20 cells at most. Created chart - 5-10. Each chart require 5-6 UDF's to create/function. The issue is quite troublesome, as each function is recalculated about 5-10 times (I used message boxes to count it). The issue is that even if I want to copy one cell and paste it somewhere, excel starts blinking and it takes a few seconds to copy. Everything works great, just blinks and slows down the Excel app... I simply do not understand why function, which should be calculated only once, recalculates over and over... Even chart with one UDF causes the problem.

Comment: The weirdest thing, which I cannot understand, is that if the UDF is stored in named range it is working just fine. But as soon as I put this named range in chart series (create a chart using this named range) everything is slooooow.

Comment: Do you really need the two-step process where you "cache" the result from `data_to_array` in a name?  Since that seems to be more of a problem than an optimization, why not write a single UDF which does everything and point a single name to that?

Comment: I suppose so. I have a few UDFs, which prepare data for series to plot them later on chart. I tried two approaches: 1) to create one UDF to retrieve data from selection to array and then use this array in the remaining UDF's. 2) to retrieve data from range to array and then calculate the rest in EACH UDF. Both ways are "pretty much" the same, as once again, the issue is in UDFs recalculating many times.

Comment: I think you may be stuck with the basic issue of multiple calculations: you can either optimize performance or try some other non-UDF approach to update your charts

Comment: It looks like it. Do you know of any way to avoid functions to calculate multiple times, or should I just move on and try different things?

Comment: Other than what Charles outlined in the page you linked to, no.  Even his "fix" doesn't prevent it being called, it just short-circuits the actual work if the input(s) are not calculated and returns directly.  The calling multiple times is just how excel works under the hood and I don't see a way to prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from trying to fix the basic problem of how many times your functions get called, you can partially address the slow-down by optimizing the basic performance:

- `Application.Match` is relatively slow unless the data being searched in on a worksheet
- Reading a range into an array is slower than reading the whole range at once using its `.Value` (assuming range is a single area)

So:

```
Sub PerfTester()
    Const ARR_SZ As Long = 10

    Dim arr(1 To ARR_SZ), i, n, t, v, m

    'populate a test array
    For i = 1 To ARR_SZ
        arr(i) = i
    Next i

    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 100000
        v = Round(Rnd * ARR_SZ, 0)
        m = IsInArray(v, arr)  'using match
    Next n
    Debug.Print Timer - t   '~ 1.7 sec

    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 100000
        v = Round(Rnd * ARR_SZ, 0)
        m = IsInArray2(v, arr) 'using a loop
    Next n
    Debug.Print Timer - t  '~0.11 sec

    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 100000
        v = data_to_array(Range("A1:A50"))  'using cell-by-cell
    Next n
    Debug.Print Timer - t   '~ 11.5 sec

    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 100000
        v = data_to_array2(Range("A1:A50"))  'using single read from range
    Next n
    Debug.Print Timer - t  '~ 2.8 sec


End Sub


Private Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function

Private Function IsInArray2(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray2 = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Private Function data_to_array(data As Range)
    Dim arrArray As Variant, cell As Range, z As Integer
    z = 0
    ReDim arrArray(1 To data.Cells.Count)
    For Each cell In data
        z = z + 1
        arrArray(z) = cell.Value
    Next cell
    data_to_array = arrArray
End Function

Private Function data_to_array2(data As Range)
    Dim arrArray As Variant, cell As Range, z As Long, v
    v = data.Value
    ReDim arrArray(1 To UBound(v, 1))
    For z = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        arrArray = v(z, 1)
    Next z
    data_to_array2 = arrArray
End Function
```

Comment: This is great. I have planned for trying to optimize my UDF's, so your idea will be a great help for me. The times clearly show how important it is to optimize the code. And it shows how far still I am from being a competent VBA guy ;) Sadly, even if I optimize my functions to the level of being "instant" it will not help if it is called 100 times, again and again... Is there any way to force functions in named ranges to be calculated only once?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prevent unnecessary additional calculations by including

```
Application.EnableEvent = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

at the start of your functions and

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

at the end of your functions. This prevents your spreadsheet from attempting to update and recalculate whenever you make a minor change. If you feel it necessary, you can add

```
Worksheet.Calculate
```

at some point in your code to force a recalculation of the current sheet.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but it does not work sadly. When I turn off events in my functions then Excel immediately shows an error of invalid formula reference. It appears that it not only stops the recalculation but also cause some other changes in Excel and it does not like it... ;-)  The calculation set to manual and then automatic does not do anything, as the function is called multiple times (for unknown reason) and the calculation mode is being changed back and forth. It looks like there is some kind of an error in Excel when you mix named ranges and UDF's...